# MySQL Finding the biggest count from a set of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have 9 columns

```
Brand, ID, M, T, W, Th, Fri, Sat, Sun
abc, 1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 7, 1,  5
```

I want to find out which of the following groups has the highest individual count.
m/t/w/th, fri, sat/sun. For example in the above table, Friday would be selected as it has the highest count.

Comment: Seriously consider normalising your schema.

Comment: And what's the difference between `/` and `,` in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no ties in values, you can do this with `greatest` and a `case` expression. If there are ties, the first value (among tied days) encountered in the `case` expression would be returned.

```
select case greatest(M, T, W, Th, Fri, Sat, Sun) 
            when M then 'Monday'
            when T then 'Tuesday'
            when W then 'Wednesday'
            when Th then 'Thursday'
            when Fri then 'Friday'
            when Sat then 'Saturday'
            when Sun then 'Sunday'
        end 
from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BRAND, ID, GREATEST (M, T, W, Th, Fri, Sat, Sun) Max_day
FROM yourtable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select brand, ID,

case 
    when M>T and M>W and M>Th and M>Fri and M>Sat and M>Sun then M
    when T>M and T>W and T>Th and T>Fri and T>Sat and T>Sun then T
    when W>T and W>M and W>Th and W>Fri and W>Sat and W>Sun then W
    when TH>T and TH>W and TH>M and TH>Fri and TH>Sat and TH>Sun then TH
    when FRI>T and FRI>W and FRI>Th and FRI>M and FRI>Sat and FRI>Sun then FRI
    when SAT>T and SAT>W and SAT>Th and SAT>Fri and SAT>M and SAT>Sun then SAT
    when SUN>T and SUN>W and SUN>Th and SUN>Fri and SUN>Sat and SUN>M then SUN
ELSE M END AS MAXDAY

FROM TBL1;
```